# Destroying a gameobject when looping back to the Main Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial on how to make games in unity and I decided to add on to the game after the tutorial had ended. I am currently in the process of adding background music to the Main Menu and the scenes that are the levels for the game. The way I added music to the main menu is by making an empty object and added the audio source component to it then added the the music I wanted for the background. The way I added music for the levels is pretty similar I pretty much did the exact same thing but I made a script and also added it to the empty because **I learned about the "DontDestroyOnLoad" so the music could continue to the next level without being interrupted but when the game loops back to the Main Menu it has the background music for the Menu and the levels overlapping so I am asking for help with the code that I came up with that I hoped that would stop it but did not work. I am also using Unity version 2020 if that helps.**

Here is the code that I came up with

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DontDestroyAudio : MonoBehaviour
{
     void Awake() 
    {
        if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "MainMenu")
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Debug.Log("This if statment works?");
        }

        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        }

        
        

        
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create an `AudioManager` script on the object with the music AudioSource. Write a method `PlayMusic(AudioClip)` in this AudioManager which changes the AudioClip being played by the AudioSource. Using a Unity implementation of the *Singleton pattern*, ensure the AudioManager can't be instantiated multiple times. Then just have an object in each scene with another script `PlayMusicOnLoad` with a serialized AudioClip which finds the AudioManager and calls `PlayMusic`. I would post this as answer with an example but I don't have a Unity environment available, sorry. Hope this helps.

Comment: To add some context to my previous comment, you would need to put the AudioManager in every scene (prefab it). Then the singleton implementation should call `DontDestroyOnLoad` for the first instance and all other instances should destroy themselves instead.

Comment: Thanks rshepp for your comment but im still pretty new to C# and unity altogether and Im sorry to ask this but could you give an example of your first comment or sort of put in layman's term so I could better wrap my head around what you are saying if possible please and thank and I understand if you cant

Comment: Lookup the concept of singleton.  It will explain and help you only have one sound thing

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make new scene that will have only your music asset in it and add load it with `SceneManager.LoadScene("YourLevelAudioScene", LoadSceneMode.Additive);` and then load and unload all level with the same parameter.
When you will go to `MainMenu` scene you will unload `YourLevelAudioScene`.
You could read more about it [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html)

Another way of doing it will be by subscribing to `SceneManager.sceneLoaded` event, more is [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html)